# Create ArrayType column in Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Structure of the Schema to be created:

```
|-- col1: boolean (nullable = true)
|-- col2: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- col2_1: boolean (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- col2_2: string (nullable = true)
```

Code to create schema:

```
val prodSchema = StructType(Array(StructField("col1", StringType), StructField("col2",ArrayType(Array(StructField("element",StructType(Array(StructField("col2_1",StringType)))))))))
```

Error:

```
found   : Array[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField]
required: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType
StructField("col2",ArrayType(Array(StructField("element",StructType(Array(StructField("col2_1",StringType)))))))
```

Any suggestions on how to correct this schema error.

Comment: What are you trying to achive?

Comment: @Alfilercio I am trying to create a schema as mentioned in the Original Schema. Since I want only the columns col1 and col2 from the entire schema which has ~100 columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can write it like this:

```
val prodSchema =
  StructType(
    List(
      StructField("col1", BooleanType),
      StructField("col2", ArrayType(
        StructType(
          List(
            StructField("col2_1", BooleanType),
            StructField("col2_2",StringType)
          )
        )
      ))
    )
  )


prodSchema.printTreeString()

root
 |-- col1: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- col2_1: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col2_2: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(  
    StructField("col1",BooleanType,false),
    StructField("col2",ArrayType(StructType(Seq(  
                       StructField("col2_1",BooleanType,true),
                       StructField("col2_2",StringType,true)
                         )))
               )))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Schema DSL](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/60be6d2ea3560143515c1ce9d0a7da416f8f595a/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.scala#L131) to create the schema:

```
val col2 = new StructType().add($"col2_1".boolean).add($"col2_2".string)
val schema = new StructType()
                 .add($"col1".boolean)
                 .add($"col2".array(col2))

schema.printTreeString()

root
 |-- col1: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- col2_1: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col2_2: string (nullable = true)
```

Hope it helps.